# Adding multiple values in ViewModel and show them in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, viewmodel

How can I pass values from a Linq select from multiple tables to a view? I have a model that shows the contents of a page. A page can have multiple contents and which contente can have multiple files.
I have a ViewModel to assembly the information of the contents:

```
namespace WeChange.ViewModels
{

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;


    public class FicheirosInformationViewModel
    {
        public int id_filec { get; set; }
        public string filenamec { get; set; }
        public string fileurlc { get; set; }
        public string fileimg { get; set; }
        public string fileextc { get; set; }
    }

    public class FicheirosConteudosViewModel
    {
        public int id_conteudo { get; set; }
        public string conttitle { get; set; }
        public string conttext { get; set; }
        public DateTime contdate { get; set; }
        public ICollection<FicheirosInformationViewModel> FicheirosInformation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In the controller I have:

```
    public ActionResult Index(FicheirosInformationViewModel FichInfoVM, FicheirosConteudosViewModel FichConteVM)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Academia Page";

        var cwc_academia = db.CWC_CONTEUDOS.Include(c => c.CWC_PAGINAS).Where(c => c.CWC_PAGINAS.id_page == 1);

        foreach (var itemfile in cwc_academia)
        {
            var FichesContes = new FicheirosConteudosViewModel();

            FichesContes.id_conteudo = itemfile.id_conteudo;
            FichesContes.conttitle = itemfile.conttitle;
            FichesContes.conttext = itemfile.conttext;
            FichesContes.contdate = itemfile.contdate;

            var ficheirosconteudos = from c in db.CWC_FILESCONTEUDOS
                                     join d in db.CWC_FICHEIROS on c.idfile equals d.id_file
                                     join e in db.CWC_TIPOSFICHEIROS on d.idfiletype equals e.id_tpfile
                                     join f in db.CWC_EXTENSOESFILES on e.id_tpfile equals f.idtpdoc
                                     where c.idconte == itemfile.id_conteudo
                                     select new FicheirosInformationViewModel()
                                     {
                                          id_filec = d.id_file,
                                          filenamec = d.filename,
                                          fileurlc = d.fileurl,
                                          fileimg = e.tipoimg,
                                          fileextc = f.extensao
                                      };
        }
        return View(FichConteVM);
    } 
}
```

And in the View:

```
@model IEnumerable<WeChange.ViewModels.FicheirosConteudosViewModel>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="divider"><div class="circle"><img src="/Images/orange.png" alt="" /></div></div>

    <div id="acad" class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h2>@Html.Raw(item.conttitle)</h2>
            @Html.Raw(item.conttext)
        </div>
    </div>

    foreach (var fich in item.FicheirosInformation)
    {
        @fich.id_filec
        <br />
        @fich.filenamec
        <br />
        @fich.fileurlc
    }
}
```

I´m always getting an error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'WeChange.ViewModels.FicheirosConteudosViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WeChange.ViewModels.FicheirosConteudosViewModel]'.

What I´m going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view is expecting a collection of `FicheirosConteudosViewModel` and you have passed a single object to it.

Try this:

```
return View(ficheirosconteudos);
```

Which will use the `FicheirosInformationViewModel` collection from your `LINQ` statement and then pass it to the View.

Comment: I get "The name 'ficheirosconteudos' does not exist in the current context".But if I undestand, if I pass ficheirosconteudos, i will not pass the FicheirosConteudosViewModel, which has the model and the select values...

Comment: @RicardoSousa - that's because `ficheirosconteudos` is declared within the foreach loop.

`ficheirosconteudos` contains multiple objects from your `LINQ` statemens, you then use this and iterate over that collection in your View.

Comment: But then I don´t have the bigger collection that is FicheirosConteudosViewModel, which has a collection of ficheirosconteudos